# time based transitions in python fsm

Tags: python, transition

I'm using python / transitions to simulate some clinical situations, and I would like to have elapsed_time as a trigger for a transition. I've thought of

1. after entering a state, have each tick increment a `time_in_state` variable, and then make the transition when `time_in_state > some value`
2. ??

Is there a particular idiomatic way to do this?

with thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could increase a counter whenever an event is triggered and only execute the transition when a certain counter limit is reached:

```
from transitions import Machine
import time


class TickModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    # called to increase the counter
    def increase_counter(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print("Current state: {0}; Counter: {1}".format(self.state, self.counter))

    # reset the counter when the state was changed
    def reset_counter(self):
        self.counter = 0

    # set the counter limit
    def limit_reached(self):
        return self.counter >= 10  # random chosen limit


states = ['A', 'B']
# trigger -- (method) name of the event
# prepare is ALWAYS called when an event is triggered;
# a transition will only be executed when all callbacks mentioned in 'conditions' return True
# after is only called when a transition has been successful
transitions = [{'trigger': 'tick', 'source': 'A', 'dest': 'B',
                'prepare': 'increase_counter', 'after': 'reset_counter',
                'conditions': 'limit_reached'}]
model = TickModel()
machine = Machine(model, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial='A')
# this part could be put into a thread for parallel processing
while model.state != 'B':
    model.tick()
    time.sleep(0.5)

# just to show that the state has been changed
model.increase_counter()
```

In case you are interested in actual time based timeouts, you can have a look at the [state features](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#state-features) which have been introduced in transitions 0.6.0.